# JavaScript For Loop shows last iteration for window.location

Tags: javascript

I've searched and found that it is something about closure and scope. But unfortunately I couldn't implement those sample solutions into my case.

Here what I'm trying to do:

```
for (var i = 100; i < 110; i++ ) {
    window.location = "www.example.com/bet.php?ip=100.100.100." + i + "&bet=55";
}
```

It should submit a bet '55' from different IP's according loop range and wait for about 5 seconds after each bet until XML result appears.

Comment: I don't think you're aware of what setting `window.location` does. Perhaps you should read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm not familiar enough about window.location. The only thing that tried Loop was because a single line without loop was working fine. For example: window.location = "www.example.com/bet.php?ip=100.100.100.101&bet=55";

Answer (score 5):

This loop will only work for a single iteration. On the first iteration, the page will be redirected to the new URL, at which point the JS stops running. You will need to use AJAX to progressively request different URLs without redirecting.

One way to do this would be, for example:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
(function redirect(i){
    if(i < 110) {
        iframe.onload = function(){
            redirect(++i);
        }
        iframe.src = "http://www.example.com/bet.php?ip=100.100.100." + i + "&bet=55";
    }
})(99)
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/udS33/

Comment: Note that there's a good chance a cross domain request will not work due to the *same origin policy*

Comment: @Phil AJAX encompasses several techniques, so you can even use an iframe that is being redirected to different URL's.

Comment: @Asad Honestly, I'm really not good at both. Would you please share a sample which will do the same thing like submitting www.example.com/bet.php?ip=100.100.100." + i + "&bet=55" in a loop. Thank you.

Comment: @user1953918 Added an example.